# Regex to find shortest matching sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sentence "in which he felt that the room was constantly going out of focus in 2082, no infarcts"

I will get the starting and ending of the sentence that needed to be extracted. Ex:- start -> in. End -> infarcts

I wanted to extract the sentence "in 2082, no infarcts"

I tried the regex `str.match(/\bin\b.*?\binfarcts\b/)`

I am getting the complete sentence"in which he felt that the room was constantly going out of focus in 2082, no infarcts" instead of "in 2082, no infarcts"

Answer (score 0):

You could add a negative lookbehind to find `in` when it isn't at the start of the sentence, using your regex:

`str.match(/(?<!^)\bin\b.*?\binfarcts\b/)`

Comment: Surely the slash delimiter needs to go before the lookbehind? But this is probably way too specific to be actually useful.

Comment: Have edited the delimiter, not sure about it being too specific as OP didn't really give a rule just one example to be captured

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing this, the regex finds the last `in` word in the sentence, and then takes everything after that till it finds a `infarcts` word.

```js
var str = 'in which he felt that the room was constantly going out of focus in 2082, no infarcts'

console.log(str.match(/(\bin\b)(?!.*\b\1\b).*infarcts/)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The non-greedy match will not skip over more text that necessary to produce a match, but it will still find the leftmost position in the string where a match is possible. If you want to push it right, you can have another prefix to skip as much as possible before the capturing match.

```
str.match(/.*(\bin\b.*?\binfarcts\b)/)[1]
```

Notice the `[1]` to pull out the first parenthesized subgroup.

Comment: This answer is working for everything. Thanks. If I directly use this function in chrome console it is working fine. If I create a string s1 for ".*(\bin\b.*?\binfarcts\b)"  the expression and create a regex using new RegExp(s1) and run str.match it is not working. Could you please help with this as well

Comment: Sorry, not much of a JavaScript person. Maybe post a separate question about that.